# NI USRP-2920 recognized by GNURadio

Tags: gnuradio, usrp

I try to operate NI USRP-2920 by GNUradio.
At the first, I typed "uhd_usrp_probe".
Result is below.

```
[INFO] [UHDlinux; GNU C++ version 4.8.4; Boost_105400; UHD_3.11.0.git-208-g1da86f9c] 
[INFO] [USRP2] Opening a USRP2/N-Series device...
[INFO] [USRP2] Current recv frame size: 1472 bytes
[INFO] [USRP2] Current send frame size: 1472 bytes
  _____________________________________________________
 /
|       Device: USRP2 / N-Series Device
|     _____________________________________________________
|    /
|   |       Mboard: N210r4
|   |   hardware: 2577
|   |   product: 30194
|   |   mac-addr: 00:80:2f:19:81:1e
|   |   ip-addr: 192.168.10.4
|   |   subnet: 255.255.255.255
|   |   gateway: 255.255.255.255
|   |   gpsdo: none
|   |   serial: 3077BE9
|   |   FW Version: 12.4
|   |   FPGA Version: 11.1
|   |   
|   |   Time sources:  none, external, _external_, mimo
|   |   Clock sources: internal, external, mimo
|   |   Sensors: mimo_locked, ref_locked
|   |     _____________________________________________________
|   |    /
|   |   |       RX DSP: 0
|   |   |   
|   |   |   Freq range: -50.000 to 50.000 MHz
|   |     _____________________________________________________
|   |    /
|   |   |       RX DSP: 1
|   |   |   
|   |   |   Freq range: -50.000 to 50.000 MHz
|   |     _____________________________________________________
|   |    /
|   |   |       RX Dboard: A
|   |   |   ID: WBX v3, WBX v3 + Simple GDB (0x0057)
|   |   |   Serial: 30733BF
|   |   |     _____________________________________________________
|   |   |    /
|   |   |   |       RX Frontend: 0
|   |   |   |   Name: WBXv3 RX+GDB
|   |   |   |   Antennas: TX/RX, RX2, CAL
|   |   |   |   Sensors: lo_locked
|   |   |   |   Freq range: 68.750 to 2200.000 MHz
|   |   |   |   Gain range PGA0: 0.0 to 31.5 step 0.5 dB
|   |   |   |   Bandwidth range: 40000000.0 to 40000000.0 step 0.0 Hz
|   |   |   |   Connection Type: IQ
|   |   |   |   Uses LO offset: No
|   |   |     _____________________________________________________
|   |   |    /
|   |   |   |       RX Codec: A
|   |   |   |   Name: ads62p44
|   |   |   |   Gain range digital: 0.0 to 6.0 step 0.5 dB
|   |   |   |   Gain range fine: 0.0 to 0.5 step 0.1 dB
|   |     _____________________________________________________
|   |    /
|   |   |       TX DSP: 0
|   |   |   
|   |   |   Freq range: -50.000 to 50.000 MHz
|   |     _____________________________________________________
|   |    /
|   |   |       TX Dboard: A
|   |   |   ID: WBX v3 (0x0056)
|   |   |   Serial: 30733BF
|   |   |   ID: WBX + Simple GDB, WBX v3 + Simple GDB, WBX v4 + Simple GDB, WBX-120 + Simple GDB (0x004f)
|   |   |   Serial: F603D5
|   |   |     _____________________________________________________
|   |   |    /
|   |   |   |       TX Frontend: 0
|   |   |   |   Name: WBXv3 TX+GDB
|   |   |   |   Antennas: TX/RX, CAL
|   |   |   |   Sensors: lo_locked
|   |   |   |   Freq range: 68.750 to 2200.000 MHz
|   |   |   |   Gain range PGA0: 0.0 to 31.0 step 1.0 dB
|   |   |   |   Bandwidth range: 40000000.0 to 40000000.0 step 0.0 Hz
|   |   |   |   Connection Type: IQ
|   |   |   |   Uses LO offset: No
|   |   |     _____________________________________________________
|   |   |    /
|   |   |   |       TX Codec: A
|   |   |   |   Name: ad9777
|   |   |   |   Gain Elements: None
```

In the next, I ran FM radio in GNURadio.
Result is below.

```
[RuntimeError: LookupError: KeyError: No devices found for ----->
Device Address:
    192.168.10.4: 

\[ERROR\] \[UHD\] Device discovery error: unknown key format: 192.168.10.4
\[ERROR\] \[UHD\] Device discovery error: unknown key format: 192.168.10.4
\[ERROR\] \[UHD\] Device discovery error: unknown key format: 192.168.10.4][1]
```

I can't understand this reason.
Could you tell me any advices?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I typed 192.168.10.4 in UHD:USRP Souurce block.
It isn't correct.
Type addr=192.168.10.4 in the block.
i'm sorry to have caused trouble.

Comment: you didn't cause trouble! That is a common mistake, and I'm happy you've documented the solution! Thank you!