# How to install NI USRP 2921 on GNURadio Companion (Ubuntu)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnuradio, usrp

I am trying to use my USRP 2921 on GNURadio with my computer which uses Ubuntu. I have read that I had to use the block UHD but GRC does not recognise the USRP. When I type "uhd_find_devices" in the terminal,  I have the message "No UHD Devices found" despite the fact that my  USRP 2921 is connected to the computer with the ethernet cable.
I used the command "uhd_images_downloader" in the Terminal but it did not help.

Can somebody help me?
Thank you!

Comment: Installing and interfacing with software defined radios is probably a better question for [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Please read [help on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33304828/when-trying-to-use-my-usrp-in-gnu-radio-i-get-a-no-devices-found-for