# Unable to detect B200 in GNU Radio

Tags: gnuradio, usrp

I am trying to demonstrate the FM Receiver using USRP B200 in GNU Radio; however, I always got an error message as follows:

```
RuntimeError: LookupError: KeyError: No devices found for ----->
Empty Device Address
```

Note that I can use `uhd_find_dvices` to successfully identify my B200.

[Flowchart in gnuradio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLZtu.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When trying to use my USRP in GNU Radio, I get a " No devices found for ----->" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33304828/when-trying-to-use-my-usrp-in-gnu-radio-i-get-a-no-devices-found-for)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is uhd images you can find more about it in [here](https://files.ettus.com/manual/page_images.html)

In windows i set UHD_IMAGES in my environment variables.