# USRP X310 not recognized via 1GbE

Tags: windows, usrp, software-defined-radio, uhd

I possess the USRP X310 with a Basic TX daughterboard installed. My plan is to use it via 10GbE together with LabView with a Win10 host machine. 
I have connected the SDR with an Ethernet cable using Port 0 and the included SFP adapter to my host PC's (1GbE) ethernet interface for network testing purposes. The ethernet adapter is configured to use the static IP `192.168.10.1`. Furthermore I have installed the UHD (`uhd_3.15.0.0-release_Winx64_VS2017.exe`). However when the device is connected and powered on, I can neither ping 198.168.10.2 nor detect it running the `uhd_find_devices.exe`. I have also started the NI-USRP Configuration Utility which I recently updated but it was not able to detect the SDR either. I do observe that none of the LEDs on the back is illuminated (especially not the Port 0 ethernet).
How can I get it working?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When trying to use my USRP in GNU Radio, I get a " No devices found for ----->" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33304828/when-trying-to-use-my-usrp-in-gnu-radio-i-get-a-no-devices-found-for)

Answer (score 0):

If you've worked with other usrps (I have a few), then you'll find the X310 to be somewhat different, to the lower models.

Anyway, there are different fpga loads / images, which corrospond to whether you are trying to connect via a 1G or 10G module.

"The PCIe interface is always available regardless of what FPGA image is loaded. Ettus ships two FPGA image variants, the **HG** or **HGS** image which has one 1 GigE interfaces and one 10 GigE interfaces, and the **XG** image which has two 10 GigE interfaces.

So you need to be sure you have the right image to connect to it via 1GE... or I expect it won't work, as it seems to be.

HTH's.