# USRP x310 responds to ping but does not responds to uhd_find_devices or uhd_usrp_probe

Tags: gnuradio, usrp, uhd

I am having some trouble with my USRP x310. This question might seem duplicate but I have already tried all the possible solution that I was able to find but I am still not able to resolve it.
Here are some of the posts that I followed and were similar to the problem I am facing.

```
1. http://lists.ettus.com/pipermail/usrp-users_lists.ettus.com/2015-January/040356.html

2. https://www.ruby-forum.com/t/a-strange-problem-with-no-uhd-devices-found-when-ping-192-168-10-2-is-ok/217561
```

I even posted a question at the NI discussion forum [here is the URL](https://forums.ni.com/t5/USRP-Software-Radio/Unable-to-find-or-probe-USRP-X310-but-responds-to-ping/m-p/4112408?profile.language=en#M5194),  But I haven't received any response. I also tried to make a post at `discuss-gnuradio@gnu.org and usrp-users@lists.ettus.com` but for some reason the question is not yet posted so now I turnig to the good old trusted stackoverflow in search of some help.

**Here is problem I am facing.**

I was able to run my USRP x310 without any problem till last week but when I turned it on this week to run some experiments using srsLTE, when I ran srsenb it started gaving error `"no compatible rf-frontend found"`. So to test the connectivity of x310 with the host computer, I ran `'uhd_find_devices' and 'uhd_usrp_probe'`
Here is the output of the commands.

```
raghav@raghav-XPS:~$ uhd_find_devices 
[INFO] [UHD] linux; GNU C++ version 7.5.0; Boost_106501; UHD_3.15.0.0-release
No UHD Devices Found

raghav@raghav-XPS:~$ uhd_usrp_probe 
[INFO] [UHD] linux; GNU C++ version 7.5.0; Boost_106501; UHD_3.15.0.0-release
Error: LookupError: KeyError: No devices found for ----->
Empty Device Address
```

Then I checked the hardware and I was able to see the sfp+ light at port 0 which is correct, so I tried to ping the x310 `'ping 192.168.10.2'` and the device responded to ping without any loss in packets. So I tried to run `'uhd_find_devices' and 'uhd_usrp_probe'` by providing the address of the device as the argument and then I was able to see the correct output.
Here is the outputs:

```
raghav@raghav-XPS:~$ uhd_find_devices --args addr=192.168.10.2
[INFO] [UHD] linux; GNU C++ version 7.5.0; Boost_106501; UHD_3.15.0.0-release
--------------------------------------------------
-- UHD Device 0
--------------------------------------------------
Device Address:
    serial: 31EC216
    addr: 192.168.10.2
    fpga: HG
    name: 
    product: X310
    type: x300

raghav@raghav-XPS:~$ uhd_usrp_probe --args addr=192.168.10.2
[INFO] [UHD] linux; GNU C++ version 7.5.0; Boost_106501; UHD_3.15.0.0-release
[INFO] [X300] X300 initialization sequence...
[INFO] [X300] Maximum frame size: 1472 bytes.
[INFO] [X300] Radio 1x clock: 200 MHz
[INFO] [GPS] No GPSDO found
[INFO] [0/DmaFIFO_0] Initializing block control (NOC ID: 0xF1F0D00000000000)
[INFO] [0/DmaFIFO_0] BIST passed (Throughput: 1319 MB/s)
[INFO] [0/DmaFIFO_0] BIST passed (Throughput: 1314 MB/s)
[INFO] [0/Radio_0] Initializing block control (NOC ID: 0x12AD100000000001)
[INFO] [0/Radio_1] Initializing block control (NOC ID: 0x12AD100000000001)
[INFO] [0/DDC_0] Initializing block control (NOC ID: 0xDDC0000000000000)
[INFO] [0/DDC_1] Initializing block control (NOC ID: 0xDDC0000000000000)
[INFO] [0/DUC_0] Initializing block control (NOC ID: 0xD0C0000000000000)
[INFO] [0/DUC_1] Initializing block control (NOC ID: 0xD0C0000000000000)
  _____________________________________________________
 /
|       Device: X-Series Device
|     _____________________________________________________
|    /
|   |       Mboard: X310
|   |   revision: 11
|   |   revision_compat: 7
|   |   product: 30818
|   |   mac-addr0: 00:80:2f:31:49:67
|   |   mac-addr1: 00:80:2f:31:49:68
|   |   gateway: 192.168.10.1
|   |   ip-addr0: 192.168.10.2
|   |   subnet0: 255.255.255.0
|   |   ip-addr1: 192.168.20.2
|   |   subnet1: 255.255.255.0
|   |   ip-addr2: 192.168.30.2
|   |   subnet2: 255.255.255.0
|   |   ip-addr3: 192.168.40.2
|   |   subnet3: 255.255.255.0
|   |   serial: 31EC216
|   |   FW Version: 6.0
|   |   FPGA Version: 36.0
|   |   FPGA git hash: fde2a94
|   |   RFNoC capable: Yes
.
.
.
.
```

I have already tried to update the fpga of the x310, redid the network connection setup and even reinstalled uhd drivers but nothing helped so far.

I would really appreciate if someone can help me with this issue.

Comment: I have administrative access to the discuss-gnuradio list. You did not post that there, at least nor as registered user... Anyway, the discuss-gnuradio list is for GNU Radio issues (and this is none). The usrp-users list is also subscribers-only, so you'll want to sign up under http://lists.ettus.com/mailman/listinfo/usrp-users_lists.ettus.com before sending a question there.

Comment: Anyways, please **actually** copy the commands you use; you've printed the output of `uhd_usrp_probe`, but claim to have run `uhd_find_devices`; not a big deal, but such inaccuracies make debugging a hell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classical case of "computer does not let through traffic from broadcast addresses" as used for device discovery.

Hence, [When trying to use my USRP in GNU Radio, I get a " No devices found for ----->" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33304828/when-trying-to-use-my-usrp-in-gnu-radio-i-get-a-no-devices-found-for?rq=1) partially applies. Make sure your PC's firewall is configured to let through packets from and for broadcast addresses.

Comment: WOW, I did not expect to get a response from you. I went through your post yesterday but I happened to skip through the firewall point and that is where I made the biggest mistake. `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 49152 -j ACCEPT` did the trick. Now everything is working as it should be.

But I still don't understand how did the firewall settings changed, because when I initially did the setup I never added any new rule to firewall and everything was working normally but suddenly one day it stopped working. 
But any ways, thanks for shedding light on it again Marcus.