# GNURadio can not find USRP n3xx but device can be pinged from host, as well as found using uhd_find_devices, uhd_usrp_prob

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion, usrp, software-defined-radio

I am using an Ettus USRP n3xx. I have connected the device to my host desktop via 1GB ethernet. I am able to ping the device using `ping <DEVICE_IP_ADDR>` and I am able to find the device using both `uhd_find_devices` and `uhd_usrp_probe`. I am also able to ping my host when I tty into the USRP. Even with all of this, GNURadio (and GNSS-SDR) is unable to find the device (The error reads "No devices found for -----> Device Address:").

I have already attempted the firewall workaround described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33304828/when-trying-to-use-my-usrp-in-gnu-radio-i-get-a-no-devices-found-for?rq=1). Any further suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: which version of UHD do you use?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I am currently using UHD 4.1.0.0.

Comment: and you're 100% sure the GNU Radio you're using is also built with, linked against and loading at runtime that version of UHD?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Now that you have mentioned it, it appears the GNURadio may be loading an different version of UHD (UHD_003.010.003.000-0-unknown). Thank you - now I need to find a way to remedy this.

Comment: the only remedy is uninstalling your current version of GNU Radio (and the UHD it links against) and installing one that was built against the version you need – 4.1.0.0; that probably implies building GNU Radio from source. The only major Linux distro I'm aware of so far that's adopted UHD 4 is Fedora 34

Comment: @MarcusMüller So no GNU Radio builds for Ubuntu 18.04 will be compatible with UHD 4+?

Comment: no binary builds available from Ubuntu themselves, no. Also, really Ubuntu 18.04 is quite old. I'd very much recommend updating, but even then, Ubuntu ships UHD3, so their GNU Radio is built against that and can't be used with any other version.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thank you for the help! I will try to downgrade UHD on my device and match it to that of GNU Radio.

Comment: That can't work. You need UHD4, older versions of UHD don't support the N3xx. It's why I wrote "The **only** remedy..."

Comment: @MarcusMüller the N310 needs UHD 3.11 and up - I have now put on 3.15 and everything runs smoothly.

Comment: argh, sorry, I confused that in my head with the X4xx

Comment: @MarcusMüller No worries. Thanks again!