# GNU Radio USRP N210

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I work on a project on GNU Radio 3.8.3.1 and I use USRP N210 on this project. When I run the flow graph it gives the following error:

```
linux; GNU C++ version 7.3.0; Boost_106501; UHD_003.010.003.000-0-unknown
```

Also, when I tried to run the command uhd_find_devices on the terminal (Ubuntu 18.04) it gives this error:

```
[INFO] [UHD] linux; GNU C++ version 7.5.0; Boost_106501; UHD_4.2.0.git-209-gf23ab721
No UHD Devices Found
```

However, when I used ping "IP address of usrp", it pinged successfully. Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: the first one is not an error, at all. The second is a duplicate:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When trying to use my USRP in GNU Radio, I get a " No devices found for ----->" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33304828/when-trying-to-use-my-usrp-in-gnu-radio-i-get-a-no-devices-found-for)

Comment: I will check it and try that solution

Comment: @MarcusMüller I am working on a networked device with 1Gbit ethernet, and I am sure that the connection is correct. Also, the IP addresses are correct.
Also, the gnurdaio flow graph opens usrp when I run the flowgraph and gives:

-- Opening a USRP2/N-Series device...
-- Current recv frame size: 1472 bytes
-- Current send frame size: 1472 bytes

Comment: @xuebin Not sure if this will help, but make sure that you are not running the command of uhd_find_devices while the flowgraph is being executed in GNU Radio. Just make sure that you have terminated the flow graph and then run the command. Because the command does not detect the device when it is already in use in GNU Radio.

Comment: @MobiZaman That did not work. It gives the same error.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I did follow all the steps on this link: https://kb.ettus.com/Building_and_Installing_the_USRP_Open-Source_Toolchain_(UHD_and_GNU_Radio)_on_Linux, and everything was perfect without getting any errors. Also, I did delete and re-install the firmware on the usrp, However, the uhd_find_devices still gives the same output (no uhd devices found), and the ping with 198.168.10.2 is unreachable.

Comment: then that is not the address of the USRP, or you have a firewall in place.

Comment: The ping with the address of the written on the usrp is successful.

Comment: I solved this issue. Thank you guys.